# Master Data Services trouble when setting up

Tags: windows-8, sql-server-2008-r2, iis-8, master-data-services

I'm having a lot of troubles trying to install and configure the IIS8 with MDS for SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2..

Now after a lot of problems solved, the web application for MDS is blowing me with this message:

Cannot open database "MDM_Sample" requested by the login.

What database is that? I have not found anything in Internet that could clarify where I could obtain this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running the MDS Configuration Manager, when they ask for the name of the database you must write 'MDM_SAMPLE'..